# Is there a way to set the value and text for Select/Radio/Checkbox using More Fields?

Tags: customization

I'm using more fields to add a "Voltage" field to one of my More Types using their More Fields plugin. I want to be able to order the posts by Voltage, but if I use the text values is doesn't order properly...my values are 4.0KV, 13.6KV, 27.6KV and 44KV.

I'd like to be able to set the value of the radio and the text so I can use 4000, 13600, 27600 and 44000 as the actual field values, but show the user 4.0KV, 13.6KV, etc.

Is this possible with More Fields?